# How to hook a callback on Angular UI Popover's trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I have used Angular UI Popover like below

```
<div popover-is-open="prfList.isProfileClosed===false" popover-trigger="'outsideClick'" popover-append-to-body="true" popover-placement="right-top" popover-class="popover1 dmspopover"
    uib-popover-template="prfList.popupUrl">

</div>
```

What I need is a way to hook a callback when the popover's trigger gets called . The popopover is getting closed successfully clicking outside..its just that I want to catch that event to execute my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have attribute `popover-is-open="prfList.isProfileClosed===false"`

You need to watch `prfList.isProfileClosed` for changes and call needed function

Comment: The popover is getting closed by two ways...first when the value of isprofileclosed is set to true ...and the other way is by just clicking outside the popover...I want to hook my logic for this second way